# Set DateTime parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer

As you can see on image below DateTime parameter type is supported in RDLC.
[image]

I'm trying to set parameter like this but this code doesn't compile with error that there is not constructor accepting this type of arguments:

```
var p = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", DateTime.Now);
LocalReport.SetParameters(p);
```

Is there a way to set DateTime or even DateTime? (nullable) as parameter so it can be used for further report calculations without converting it to string ?

Comment: From what I can see here, your parameter is named "ReportParameter1" and you're naming it "dateParam" ... But maybe that is just for the example.

Comment: It's only for example, but I will change this in question to be more clear.

Comment: Does it support DateTime and not a string in ISO format?

Comment: Your code looks fine ... I do the same except in vb.net ... Can you take a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter.ReportParameter(string, string)' has some invalid arguments Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Answer (score 2):

None of the constuctors for ReportParameter take a DateTime. [See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportparameter.reportparameter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You can probably make it work with:

```
var p = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I don't wont to do. I need the exact variable so it can be used later from report code behind. I know I can pass DateTime Ticks as a string value and cast it later from report code. But I was wandering why is there report parameter type DateTime if I can't really use it ?

Answer (score 0):

These is old question, but recently I run to this problem when trying to pass nullable datetime as parameter to report.
The way I deal with them is like this;

```
  private DateTime? datumOd = null;
  private DateTime datOd;
  datOd = datumOd.HasValue ? datumOd.Value : DateTime.Now.AddYears(-20);
  if (datumOd.HasValue)
        {
            parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("DatumOd", datOd.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy 
            HH:mm"));
        }
        else
        {
            parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("DatumOd");
        }
```